# Unable to delete a file in Windows using javascript in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code which tries to delete a file on a windows 7 machine:

```
    // check if this item has an uploaded image file
    var imageFullPathName = __dirname + "/../public/images/" + req.params.itemId;
    logger.log("imageFullPathName = " + imageFullPathName);
    var normalizedPathName = path.normalize(imageFullPathName);
    logger.log("normalizedPathName = " + normalizedPathName);

    // delete the image if it exists
    fs.exists(normalizedPathName, function(exists) {
        console.log("Found the file: " + normalizedPathName);
        normalizedPathName = normalizedPathName.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
        console.log("New path name = " + normalizedPathName);
        fs.unlink(normalizedPathName, function(err){
            if (err){
                console.error("Error in call to fs.unlink");
            }
        });
    });
```

I get the following output:

> imageFullPathName =
>   C:\IronKey\hes\cscie-71\project\medical-interchange\routes/../public/images/5658e5612103cb2c41000006
>
> normalizedPathName =
>   C:\IronKey\hes\cscie-71\project\medical-interchange\public\images\5658e5612103cb2c41000006
>
> New path name =
>   C:\\IronKey\\hes\\cscie-71\\project\\medical-interchange\\public\\images\\5658e5612103cb2c41000006
>
> Error in call to fs.unlink

The file in question does indeed exist when I look for it using a DOS shell.  It also doesn't matter what I do to the new path name, I can never delete the file.  If I leave the path with single back slashes by commenting out the call to `normalizedPathName.replace()`, it still fails.  However, if I manually create a string like this it works:

> fs.unlink("c:\\IronKey\\hes\\cscie-71\\project\\medical-interchange\\public\\images\\5658e5612103cb2c41000006",
>   function(err){ ...

What do I have to do to delete this file?  I'm totally stumped.

I modified the code as recommended by josh3736 as follows but I get a ENOENT error.  The file clearly does exist because I opened it in my editor using the EXACT full path name reported in the error message:

```
        // check if this item has an uploaded image file
        var imageFullPathName = path.join(__dirname, "../public/images",
                                          sanitize(req.params.itemId));
        logger.log("imageFullPathName = " + imageFullPathName);

        fs.unlink(imageFullPathName, function(err){
            //if (err.code != 'ENOENT'){
            if (err){
                logger.log("Error in call to fs.unlink", err);
            }
            else{
                logger.log("No file found");
            }
            logger.log("Delete Success");
        });
```

And the error message follows:
Error in call to fs.unlink { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'C:\\IronKey\\hes\\cscie-71\\project\\medical-interchange\\public\\images\\5658fd27fca1b3bc3d00000e']

Comment: Why do you do `fs.exists()` with one version of `normalizedPathName` and then you try to change it before deleting?   Also, `fs.exists()` is an anti-pattern.  Just attempt the delete and deal with an error if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm really new to javascript and node. Could you please explain what "anti-pattern means"?

Comment: Now to answer your question: The fs.exists() call works with the path that pass it.  The call to fs.unlink() fails and I was trying to find a way to make it work. There is literally no other reason.

Comment: Anti-pattern means "a bad way to do things".  You need to stop changing the path and just call `fs.unlink()` on the desired path with no `fs.exists()` call.  If it doesn't work, then look at exactly what error is returned and diagnose using that.  `fs.exists()` is deprecated because of concurrency issues.  In a multi-tasking OS, the file can be removed between the call to `fs.exists()` and then call to `fs.unlink()` by some other process.  And, you can just call `fs.unlink()` and handle an error if the file did not exist.  There is no reason for the `fs.exists()` call.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. You are blindly trusting user input.  An attacker need only request a URL with the `itemId` set to something like `%2E%2E%2F%2E%2E%2F%2E%2E%2FWindows`.  Express would unescape this in `req.params` to `../../../Windows`, and there goes your server.

   In general, remember to be extremely careful when dealing with untrusted input (and *anything* that comes in over HTTP is untrusted).  In this case, use something like [sanitize-filename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-filename) to make sure nothing naughty is in the input.
2. `fs.exists` is an anti-pattern.  Some other process might add or remove the file in question between your call to `exists` and whatever you do next.  Instead, call `unlink` unconditionally -- if you get an error with `err.code == 'ENOENT'`, the file didn't exist; just ignore the error.
3. Why `normalizedPathName = normalizedPathName.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");`?  You have a valid path that you're making invalid (`C:\foo\bar` → `C:\\foo\\bar`), so of course it doesn't work.
4. When assembling a path, use `path.join`, not string concatenation.  It will deal with slashes (`\` vs `/`), making your code portable.

Taking this all together,

```
var imageFullPathName = path.join(
                                    __dirname,
                                    "../public/images",
                                    sanitizeFilename(req.params.itemId)
                                );

fs.unlink(imageFullPathName, function(err){
    if (err) {
        if (err.code != 'ENOENT') {
            // handle actual errors here
            console.error("Error in call to fs.unlink", err);
        }
        // else there was no file, handle that if you need to
    }
    // else delete success, handle that if you need to
});
```

---

Since you mentioned that your code fails even when commenting out the backslash `replace` line:

Your code *should* work that way.  What is the actual error?  My first guess would be a permissions problem.

Comment: The file most definitely does exist as I opened the file in my editor using the EXACT path name reported in the error message above.

Comment: I included the modified code and the full error message in the original question above as I did not have enough characters to do it in a comment.

Comment: Here is the error: 
Error in call to fs.unlink { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'C:\\IronKey\\hes\\cscie-71\\project\\medical-interchange\\public\\images\\5658fd27fca1b‌​3bc3d00000e']

Comment: It's weird that the error code has double back slashes while the actual file name does not.  Here is the output from logging the imageFullPathName:

imageFullPathName = C:\IronKey\hes\cscie-71\project\medical-interchange\public\images\5658fd27fca1b3bc3d00000e

Comment: One other comment, I did modify the code slightly in order to determine the error by removing "!= ENOENT".

Comment: `console.log(new Buffer(imageFullPathName).toString('hex'))` and paste the result here

Comment: I have some really strange stuff going on in my environment.  After fixing some other problems in my test code, the image deletion code started deleting the files but I'm still getting the ENOENT error.  It's weird, I'm now getting ENOENT but the file is successfully deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Command Line to delete file permanently instead of `fs.unlink`:

```
exec(`del ${imageFullPathName}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
});
```